# Kafka data loss

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, librdkafka

we are using producer on one server ‘x’ and consumer on other server says ‘y’.We stopped kafka service on consumer ‘y’.We are sending data from x to y . Few messages are visible after starting kafka on ‘‘y’’ other messages or data is getting lost.
We have added below properties:

```
"message.send.max.retries", "200"
"retry-backoff-ms", "2000"
 "delivery.timeout.ms", "150000",
"acks", "all"
"max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", "1"
```

But getting errstr=No such configuration property: “delivery.timeout.ms” for each property.

How can we reloved it.
We have checked version with below api:
rd_kafka_version_str()
kafka version:0.11.6

What configuration needs to be done to prevent data loss and which version of librdkafka is compatible with these configuration